# can not find the declaration of element 'resources'

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, adobecreativesdk

I trying to add Adobe Creative Sdk into Android app ,I follow this(https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/gettingstarted/index.html) tutorial ,but when I synic the project following error show on logcat...

```
C:\Users\Muzamil Hussain\AndroidStudioProjects\SwitchApp\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml
Error:(2599, 44) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:textColorHint' with value '@color/hint_foreground_material_light').
Error:(2599, 44) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:textColorHint' with value '@color/hint_foreground_material_light').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

for value.xml file.

my gradle app file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
/* 1) Apply the Gradle Retrolambda Plugin */
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.muzamil_hussain.switchapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders = [appPackageName: "dfc,,,,myapi key........mmmm"]
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    /* 2) Compile for Java 1.8 or greater */
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    /* 3) Exclude duplicate licenses */
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        pickFirst 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }

    // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5]'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.4'
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.1186'
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.6.3'
    compile 'com.localytics.android:library:3.8.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this build.gradle(project: name)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        /* 1) Add the Gradle Retrolambda Plugin */
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.0-beta4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

        /* 2) Add mavenCentral */
        mavenCentral()

        /* 3) Add the Creative SDK Maven repo URL */
        maven {
            url 'https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/'
        }
        maven {
            url 'http://maven.localytics.com/public'
        }


    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: have you changed your appcompat library and such. this issue could be because of resources which were in one version of sdk but not in other.

Comment: i set appcompat library 24.0.3

Comment: compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

Comment: change it to earlier version for quick fix otherwise you will have to dig in deeper

Comment: it's worked on other demo project but when Integrating to above project then give error.

Comment: your project must be using those resources from earlier versions which is not in v7:24.0.3 or find it's usages

Comment: which versions should I use?

Comment: C:\Users\Muzamil Hussain\AndroidStudioProjects\SwitchApp\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml 
file path

Comment: please help me to solve this problem... Bali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable android support.

Go to File>Settings>Plugins then enable it.